# p6spy binding variable mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, querydsl, p6spy

The library of p6spy is "con.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-springpbootpstarter:1.9.0"
And since I use JPA and QueryDSL, I wanted to check if the variable was properly bound, so I used p6spy.

Here, using JPA's Multi-Tenancy method, every query contains tenant_id.

So if you look at the example query
select
i1_0.id,
......
from
inspection i1_0
where
i1_0.tenant_id =true
and i1_0.enabled = null

As above, the query flies

However, looking at the where clause, tenant_id = true seems to have reversed the order of enabled = null at the bottom, so the binding variable is pushed.

This phenomenon continues to occur in other queries. What could be the cause?

I uploaded the latest version and looked for multi-tanancy support, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.